# Server not recieving message - Java

Tags: java, client, server, lan

I have a Server and a client where in my Server UI, I have 3 JLabel using the MouseClick i communicate to the indiviual clients connected to my server. When I click on the `JLabel1` messsage is going to `Client1` where when `Client1` recieves message it should respond but it is not responding to the server when it recieves message from it. Hope someone guide me whats wrong with my code.

//SERVER

```
void connect_clients()
    {
        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(7700);
            jButton1.setText("Server Running!");
            jButton1.setEnabled(false);
                while (true) {

                    socket = listener.accept();
                    socketList.add(socket);

             //RECIEVE METHOD FROM CLIENT WILL COME HERE.

                }

            }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "5"+ex);
        }
    }
 *******here when i click my jlabel1,message is goign to 1st client ,it should respond on seeing the message from client. but it is not.****




private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

    PrintWriter out;
     try {
         socket = socketList.get(0);
         //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, socket);
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
         out.println("PC 1");

     } catch (IOException ex) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "1"+ex);}
```

//CLIENT

```
void connect_server() throws IOException
    {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
            String serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Enter IP Address of a machine that is\n" +
                            "running the date service on port 9090:");
            s = new Socket(serverAddress, 7700);

            while(true){
                BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            String answer = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(answer);
                if(answer != null)
                {

                    //respond method to server will come here.
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Answer is not null");
               }

            }

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the `BufferedReader` outside the loop; in fact at the same time as the socket. And if `readLine()` returns `null` you should close it.